# How to link a Youtube account to an embedded YTPlayerView player in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-iframe-api, ytplayerview

I have an embedded Youtube player in my iPhone app. I'm using the **youtube-ios-player-helper** library. What I want to achieve is to authenticate the user and then for the videos he watches using the embedded **YTPlayerView** player (playing inline) to register on his watched videos history (like if he was using the native Youtube app or the website). I'd appreciate any help as I haven't found how to link a Youtube account to the embedded player using this helper library. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The `YTPlayerView` class is just a wrapper around a `UIWebView`.  You will need to load the sign-in page (or load youtube.com have the user click the login link, I think it might be session-specific), and then on a successful log in load the private video you want to play.